How to Create the Rotating "B Cube" Effect from Bridge Theme Demo?
I’m trying to replicate a specific effect from the Bridge theme demo. You can check out the page here: https://bridgelanding.qodeinteractive.com/tour/.
In this demo, there’s a section where, as you scroll, the phrase "200000 + user" rotate and form a 3D cube. It’s a seamless and interactive effect that reacts beautifully to scrolling.
I want to know the exact process or tools/plugins needed to recreate this effect:
Is it a custom-built feature or part of a plugin (like Slider Revolution or GSAP)?
If it’s custom-coded, are there libraries (e.g., Three.js, GSAP ScrollTrigger) involved?
Any advice on implementing this in WPBakery?
The rotating cube is exactly what I need for my project. Any detailed guidance, tutorials, or code snippets would be hugely appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Current example uses gsap. You can inspect the code and reverse engineer it or visit gsap forums for examples and help. Here you can share what you have done so far and if you have issues with specific part gl!
